# Crypto js encrypted string not decrypt in php

Tags: php, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am using following js code to encrypt string

```
var text = 'should be decrypted!';
var key = 'HighlySecretKeyForJsEncryption!!';
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key);
console.log(encrypted.toString());
```

output : U2FsdGVkX19vf+s6/+eB8A+3iKFCl1A0e+oe0BSbcMVGxb64FL35Q3CB/LZNu4ng

and this what I did in php to decrypt this

```
function decrypt($toDecrypt) {
    $key = "HighlySecretKeyForJsEncryption!!";
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $toDecrypt = base64_decode($toDecrypt);
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, substr($toDecrypt, $iv_size), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, substr($toDecrypt, 0, $iv_size)));
}
```

But this is not working, it gives me garbage string.

Comment: base64_decode($toDecrypt); Where did you base64 encode it?

Comment: Not working if also remove base64_decode

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677236/encryption-in-javascript-and-decryption-with-php.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, that's it. You can vote to close now.

Answer (score -1):

From [docs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/#Quick-start_Guide):

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
```

> CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the
>   variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase,
>   then it will generate a 256-bit key.

You probabily need to pass the constant `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` when decrypting php-side

More about AES encryption / decrytption in php: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422787/4499267

Comment: Using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 no luck!

Comment: CryptoJS only supports AES, but `RIJNDAEL_256` is not AES anymore. Only `RIJNDAEL_128` is compatible with AES.

Comment: Please notice that the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) says that The Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) is also known as Rijndael