# AES encryption with CryptoJS and decryption with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt a username sent via POST request to my server (written in Codeigniter 3), so I'm encrypting on the client side with [CryptoJS](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS) like so:

```
var user = $('.user').val();
var key = "<? echo($key);?>"; //$key is created on the server side
var encUser = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(user, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
}).toString();
```

I get a fine looking 64 characters long string, which I send to my server.

On my server (running CodeIgniter 3) I am using the CI [encryption](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html) library and I'm loading it as required, but when I try to decrypt the string like so:

```
$this->encryption->decrypt($this->input->post('encUser'), array(
    'cipher' => 'aes-128',
    'mode' => 'cbc',
    'hmac' => FALSE,
    'key' => $key
));
```

the function returns `(bool)false`, meaning something went wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: not sure how much I need to encrypt with `iv` because the CI library just uses the first 16 chars from the string itself.

** **EDIT** **

I'm creating my `$kay` (passphrase) with the help of the [random_int](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) polyfill and this is my function:

```
private function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
{
    $str = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Which i am calling `random_str(32)`;

Example generated key: `1xB8oBQgXGPhcKoD0QkP1Uj4CRZ7Sy1c`

** **UPDATE** **
thanks to Artjom.B's answer(and chat `:)` ) we got it working, using his answer's client side code and fixing the server side code to be:

```
$user = $this->encryption->decrypt(base64_decode($this->input->post('encUser')), array(
        'cipher' => 'aes-256',
        'mode' => 'cbc',
        'hmac' => FALSE,
        'key' => $key
    ));
```

and now everything is working.

Comment: @RyanVincent, but how can i encrypt without the key?

Comment: the thing is, there is no where i can use the `iv` on the server side, the lib just takes the first 16 chars from the string and uses that as the `iv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CryptoJS, if `key` is a string, then it will assume that `key` is actually a password, generate a random salt and derive the actual key and IV from password+salt (this is done in an OpenSSL-compatible way through `EVP_BytesToKey`).

CodeIgniter's Encryption library doesn't support this type of key derivation. You will either have to change your CryptoJS code to pass in a parsed `WordArray`:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("<? echo(bin2hex($key));?>");
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var encUser = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(user, key, {
    iv: iv
}).ciphertext;
return iv.concat(encUser).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Since the IV is written in front of the ciphertext, CodeIgniter should read it correctly and it doesn't have to be specified explicitly. Make sure that `key` is correctly encoded as Hex or Base64, because binary encoding doesn't work in JavaScript correctly. Also, at the PHP side, the ciphertext must be decoded from Base64.

You could also implement `EVP_BytesToKey` in PHP as I've shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678978/1816580).

Comment: Useing `base64_decode()` on the encrypted username gave me this:`�%؋{���?{!�
����i�v�w���Kse��2X�c�;��*A;` and the decrypt function returned `false` again

Comment: Have you encoded the `$key` to Hex for JavaScript, but used the raw `$key` for decryption?

Comment: I used it raw, I tried to parse it now but i'm not able to parse it correctly on the server for some reason

Comment: Can you show how your key (example) looks and how you've created it?

Comment: key example: `1xB8oBQgXGPhcKoD0QkP1Uj4CRZ7Sy1c`

Comment: There is something wrong with how you're generating the key. You've requested 16 bytes, but you've presented a key with 32 bytes. So, you're using AES-256 and not AES-128. So you should change the `'cipher'`. I've also made an edit to include correct key encoding at the JavaScript side.

Comment: My bad, i am requesting a 32 bytes key, iv'e edited that in my question now.
is the `base64_decode()` still needed for the encrypted username?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113848/discussion-between-firebrand-and-artjom-b).