# How can I convert the following Node.js crypto buffer to PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, cryptography

I am having some hard time figuring out how to convert the following code to PHP;

```
const envelope = JSON.stringify({ v: value, a: Cryptiles.randomString(2) });
const cipher = Crypto.createCipher('aes256', key);

let enc = cipher.update(envelope, 'utf8', 'binary');
enc += cipher.final('binary');

return (new Buffer(enc, 'binary')).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, ':').replace(/\=/g, '');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll need an EVP_BytesToKey implementation like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27678978/1816580). Note that Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for the response! I didn't want to have it completely translated, just a small clue into the good direction :) I'll look into your given implementation, thanks!