# How to add encryption key in SHA256 algorithm in php?

Tags: php, laravel, hash, sha256

I want to encrypt some data uisng SHA256 hashing algorithm

```
<?php
 $encryption_key = "aldskfje49345rgaefa";

 echo hash('sha256', "hello world");

?>
```

Comment: The Hash::make function creates and uses a 22-length random string as a salt to generate the password

Comment: Sir, I have a problem where my friend is using C#. He has encrypted a string using SHA256 algorithm and he has also provided me an encryption key. The thing we have to achieve is I will encrypt a string from here and he will decrypt it using that particular encryption key. So I have to pass that encryption key to that crypt function. Hope you have understood my problem.

Comment: This is not possible with SHA256, its not meant to be decrypted. Dont get me wrong. You can but only with brute force. its meant to be as a verification such as a password. You can use `aes` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482456/6091308

Answer (score 1):

Try Using hash_hmac() Like this hash_hmac('sha256',);

> Read the Manual [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)

Just a suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
echo hash('sha256', "hello world");
```

You are not **encrypting** your data but you are **hashing** them.

The difference between both ?

**Hashing** is one way. You generate an unique and irreversible hash. 
**Encrypting** is two way. You can encrypt your data with a key and decrypt with the same key.

So in your situation, you should avoid using SHA256 algorithm. Instead, I recommand you to use `Crypt` facade provided by Laravel. The key used for encrypting your data is your APP_KEY environnement variable (which is generated when you install your project).
If you have not this, you can simply generate it by execute this command :

```
php artisan key:generate
```

So, you will need to share the key with your friend, and use the same algorithm. I let you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/encryption#introduction) about Crypt Facade.

Comment: Yes but I want to encrypt some data with the key a friend of mine provided to me. How can I do this ?? Note: He has used SHA256 algorithm

Comment: You won't be able to encrypt your data with algorithm SHA256. As I explained, SHA256 will HASH your data and not ENCRYPT them. You and your friend need to change the process and use Encrypt algorithm.