# Encrypt and Decrypt id from javascript to laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, url, encryption

Javascript

```
window.location.href = "{{ url('student/take_test')}}/"+encrypted;
```

javascript id passing above method. encrypt id in javascript

Laravel

decrypt in laravel

```
Route::get('/student/take_test/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Student\StudentController@take_test')
```

is that possible?

Comment: Here is a similar question hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677236/encryption-in-javascript-and-decryption-with-php

Answer (score 0):

```
var encrypted = your_id;
var url = "{{ url('student/take_test/id')}}";
var new_url = url.replace('id', encrypted);

window.location.href = new_url;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its not i am expecting,

javascript url is id is passing in url encrypt that and decrypt in laravel