# Laravel decrypt what CryptoJS encrypt. (laravel v9, aes, Node, pasport)

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, encryption, cryptojs

I am sorry for my English.

The project migrates from Node to Laravel.

I'm the junior, maybe someone will tell me the right direction in the search)))

How to decrypt in Laravel what is encrypted in cryptojs?

In Node, they use CryptoJS and worked with passwords like this:

Encrypt

```
password: cryptojs.encrypt(JSON.stringify(req.body.password), secretKey).toString(),
```

Decrypt

```
cryptojs.decrypt(user.password.toString(), secretKey);
```

---

I'm trying to implement a password-checking mechanism in Laravel.
I have secretKey, old password, db stored data.

Tried this

```
$newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter(config('app.secret_key'), config('app.cipher'));
$decrypted = $newEncrypter->decrypt( $encrypted );
```

tinker output: `Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException  The payload is invalid.`

Tried this and it return false

```
public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
{
   $hashedBytes = base64_decode($hashedValue);
   $iv = substr($hashedBytes, 0, openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
   $encrypted = substr($hashedBytes, openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
   $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'aes-256-cbc', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

   return $value === $decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Try `$newEncrypter->decrypt( $encrypted , true);`

Comment: The user @artjom-b answered there - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678978/4253966