# Java code to decrypt the node.js encrypted string

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, aes

I have a server which encrypts the some data using

```
var key = new Buffer('Kay8u5Dev5al7', 'utf-8');

var encrypt = function(key, data) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', key);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}
```

Now I want to decrypt the data back using a java client.

Though I referred some examples to decrypt in java I could'nt get the data back. I am using JCE security jars at the client side.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Show the code that you tried and the errors that you received.

Comment: Note that `crypto.createCipher` uses a password and not a key. You would need to replicate `EVP_bytesToKey` in Java.

Comment: Late but @ArtjomB.: you only need `EVP_BytesToKey` for the case no salt, MD5, and one iteration (!!), which is relatively easy, plus there are several Qs with the needed code if you look.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Good thing, I've done that already with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29152379/1816580) of mine.