# Follow same encryption in android as developed in CryptoJS

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I would like to encrypt this javascript code in android.

```
let base64Key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);

let encryptedValue = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, base64Key, {
mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
iv: base64Key
});
return encryptedValue.toString();
```

Code:

```
String encryptedKey = Base64.encodeToString(keyword.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptedKey.getBytes(), algorithm);
Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
chiper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encVal = chiper.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.NO_WRAP);
return encryptedValue;
```

But it returns a completely different value.

The first line of the code itself returns a different value in both cases:

So I got this part working.
I just needed to add the following lines to the android code:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(key.getBytes());
        String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(decoded);
```

This is the equivalent of `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);` this line in CryptoJS.

But still trying to figure out the end result though. Both are different.

Comment: having same issue  can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working in Android using the below code, if anyone else faces the issue:

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String value) {
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP), "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode(key.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);

        return new String(Base64.encode(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.NO_WRAP));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i'm getting null as result and it is showing an exception as java.security.invalidkeyexception: unsupported key size: 20 bytes.Could you please help me regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

I am also having same issue but finally, i got a Class from Git.

> AESHelper.decrypt("your secret key","encryptedText")

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESHelper {

    /**
     *
     * Conforming with CryptoJS AES method
     * **** YOU NEED TO ADD "JCE policy" to have ability to DEC/ENC 256 key-lenght with AES Cipher ****
     *
     */

 
    static int KEY_SIZE = 256;
    static int IV_SIZE = 128;
    static String HASH_CIPHER = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
    static String AES = "AES";
    static String CHARSET_TYPE = "UTF-8";
    static String KDF_DIGEST = "MD5";


    // Seriously crypto-js, what's wrong with you?
    static String APPEND = "Salted__";

    /**
     * Encrypt
     * @param password passphrase
     * @param plainText plain string
     */
    public static String encrypt(String password,String plainText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] saltBytes = generateSalt(8);
        byte[] key = new byte[KEY_SIZE/8];
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_SIZE/8];

        EvpKDF(password.getBytes(CHARSET_TYPE), KEY_SIZE, IV_SIZE, saltBytes, key, iv);

        SecretKey keyS = new SecretKeySpec(key, AES);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(HASH_CIPHER);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyS, ivSpec);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(CHARSET_TYPE));

        // Thanks kientux for this: https://gist.github.com/kientux/bb48259c6f2133e628ad
        // Create CryptoJS-like encrypted !

        byte[] sBytes = APPEND.getBytes(CHARSET_TYPE);
        byte[] b = new byte[sBytes.length + saltBytes.length + cipherText.length];
        System.arraycopy(sBytes, 0, b, 0, sBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, b, sBytes.length, saltBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, b, sBytes.length + saltBytes.length, cipherText.length);

        byte[] bEncode = Base64.encode(b);

        return new String(bEncode);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt
     * Thanks Artjom B. for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29152379/4405051
     * @param password passphrase
     * @param cipherText encrypted string
     */
    public static String decrypt(String password,String cipherText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] ctBytes = Base64.decode(cipherText.getBytes(CHARSET_TYPE));
        byte[] saltBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(ctBytes, 8, 16);
        byte[] ciphertextBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(ctBytes, 16, ctBytes.length);
        byte[] key = new byte[KEY_SIZE/8];
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_SIZE/8];

        EvpKDF(password.getBytes(CHARSET_TYPE), KEY_SIZE, IV_SIZE, saltBytes, key, iv);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(HASH_CIPHER);
        SecretKey keyS = new SecretKeySpec(key, AES);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyS, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes);
        return new String(plainText);
    }

    private static byte[] EvpKDF(byte[] password, int keySize, int ivSize, byte[] salt, byte[] resultKey, byte[] resultIv) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return EvpKDF(password, keySize, ivSize, salt, 1, KDF_DIGEST, resultKey, resultIv);
    }

    private static byte[] EvpKDF(byte[] password, int keySize, int ivSize, byte[] salt, int iterations, String hashAlgorithm, byte[] resultKey, byte[] resultIv) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        keySize = keySize / 32;
        ivSize = ivSize / 32;
        int targetKeySize = keySize + ivSize;
        byte[] derivedBytes = new byte[targetKeySize * 4];
        int numberOfDerivedWords = 0;
        byte[] block = null;
        MessageDigest hasher = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm);
        while (numberOfDerivedWords < targetKeySize) {
            if (block != null) {
                hasher.update(block);
            }
            hasher.update(password);
            block = hasher.digest(salt);
            hasher.reset();

            // Iterations
            for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
                block = hasher.digest(block);
                hasher.reset();
            }

            System.arraycopy(block, 0, derivedBytes, numberOfDerivedWords * 4,
                    Math.min(block.length, (targetKeySize - numberOfDerivedWords) * 4));

            numberOfDerivedWords += block.length/4;
        }

        System.arraycopy(derivedBytes, 0, resultKey, 0, keySize * 4);
        System.arraycopy(derivedBytes, keySize * 4, resultIv, 0, ivSize * 4);

        return derivedBytes; // key + iv
    }

    private static byte[] generateSalt(int length) {
        Random r = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[length];
        r.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
}
```

Comment: For base64 get it from here.

implementation 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19.4'

Comment: This is the exact solution I was looking for, this generates the exact same value compatible with CryptoJS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example) and [page on Java Cryptographic Extensions](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_the_Java_Cryptographic_Extensions)

Answer (score 0):

To turn a text string (UTF-8 encoded) into a base-64 string, you need:

```
var textString = 'Hello world'; // Utf8-encoded string
var words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(textString); // WordArray object
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(words); // string: 'SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
```

Comment: I can't change the javascript code. I only have access to the android code. So I need to change it in android. How do I change this in android?

Comment: the problem is, in javascript you convert the key in an "Word Array"  and in the java code you convert the key in an 64-base-coded string.  thats not the same

Comment: Yup. I read that "Most result objects in CryptoJS are WordArray types. When you call the toString() function on such an object, you get a Hex-encoded string of that binary object."

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me,

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptionUtils {
    private static final String key = "123456$#@$^@RRRR";//16 characters
    private static final String initVector = "123456$#@$^@RRRR";//16 characters

    public static String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());

            // byte[] finalCiphertext = new byte[encrypted.length+2*16];
            return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```