# Encrypt from android and decrypt in CryptoJS

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am very much new to AES encryption and decryption. In my app, I have to decrypt the data which I get from the server. The data I receive is encrypted using the CryptoJS library. The decryption works pretty much fine. But while posting the data to the server, I have to again encrypt the data and send it to the server, which is not giving proper encryption.  I have followed [This Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432896/cryptojs-aes-encryption-and-java-aes-decryption) for decryption which is working fine. I will post my decryption code below. Please help.

For decryption:

```
 public  static String Decrypt(String Encrpyt , String Key ) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    byte[] cipherData = Base64.decode(Encrpyt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] saltData = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherData, 8, 16);

    MessageDigest md5 = null;
    try {
        md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final byte[][] keyAndIV = GenerateKeyAndIV(32, 16, 1, saltData, Key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), md5);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[0], "AES");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[1]);

    byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherData, 16, cipherData.length);
    Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    aesCBC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    byte[] decryptedData = aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted);
    String decryptedText = new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    System.out.println(decryptedText);
    return decryptedText;
}

public static byte[][] GenerateKeyAndIV(int keyLength, int ivLength, int iterations, byte[] salt, byte[] password, MessageDigest md) {

    int digestLength = md.getDigestLength();
    int requiredLength = (keyLength + ivLength + digestLength - 1) / digestLength * digestLength;
    byte[] generatedData = new byte[requiredLength];
    int generatedLength = 0;

    try {
        md.reset();

        // Repeat process until sufficient data has been generated
        while (generatedLength < keyLength + ivLength) {

            // Digest data (last digest if available, password data, salt if available)
            if (generatedLength > 0)
                md.update(generatedData, generatedLength - digestLength, digestLength);
            md.update(password);
            if (salt != null)
                md.update(salt, 0, 8);
            try {
                md.digest(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
            } catch (DigestException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // additional rounds
            for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
                md.update(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
                md.digest(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
            }

            generatedLength += digestLength;
        }

        // Copy key and IV into separate byte arrays
        byte[][] result = new byte[2][];
        result[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(generatedData, 0, keyLength);
        if (ivLength > 0)
            result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(generatedData, keyLength, keyLength + ivLength);

        return result;

    } catch (DigestException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
        // Clean out temporary data
        Arrays.fill(generatedData, (byte)0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding Salt when encrypting right? you should consider this in server decryption

Comment: Hi Animesh Jena, I need also. any solution?

Comment: So, what's the question here? Translate this android decryption code to CryptoJS decryption code? StackOverflow is not a code translation service. Have you tried anything yet? Can you show us your results (code and errors)? (also @RanjithKumar)

Comment: @ArtjomB.please look this question. I explained clearly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774278/cryptojs-java-aes-encryption-result-mismatch

Comment: @RanjithKumar: I finally resolved it by adding the javascript file to encrypt the data instead of writing java method in my project while using Rhino library to execute the javascript code in android. Please follow the same. If facing any problem, let me know and I will elaborate.

Comment: Please post your encryption part code as answer. I will offer bounty to you

Comment: @AnimeshJena can you post your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Please find the below snippet. Add it in a .js file named aes.js. Create a Raw folder inside res folder. Inside the Raw folder add the aes.js file.

You can see in the javascript code, there are 2 methods called encryption() and decryption() which we will be using in our code.

```js
/*
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(u,p){var d={},l=d.lib={},s=function(){},t=l.Base={extend:function(a){s.prototype=this;var c=new s;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty("init")||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty("toString")&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}},
r=l.WordArray=t.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=p?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||v).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,e=a.words,j=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(j%4)for(var k=0;k<a;k++)c[j+k>>>2]|=(e[k>>>2]>>>24-8*(k%4)&255)<<24-8*((j+k)%4);else if(65535<e.length)for(k=0;k<a;k+=4)c[j+k>>>2]=e[k>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,e);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<<
32-8*(c%4);a.length=u.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=t.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],e=0;e<a;e+=4)c.push(4294967296*u.random()|0);return new r.init(c,a)}}),w=d.enc={},v=w.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var e=[],j=0;j<a;j++){var k=c[j>>>2]>>>24-8*(j%4)&255;e.push((k>>>4).toString(16));e.push((k&15).toString(16))}return e.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,e=[],j=0;j<c;j+=2)e[j>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(j,
2),16)<<24-4*(j%8);return new r.init(e,c/2)}},b=w.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var e=[],j=0;j<a;j++)e.push(String.fromCharCode(c[j>>>2]>>>24-8*(j%4)&255));return e.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,e=[],j=0;j<c;j++)e[j>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(j)&255)<<24-8*(j%4);return new r.init(e,c)}},x=w.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(b.stringify(a)))}catch(c){throw Error("Malformed UTF-8 data");}},parse:function(a){return b.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}},
q=l.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=t.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new r.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){"string"==typeof a&&(a=x.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var c=this._data,e=c.words,j=c.sigBytes,k=this.blockSize,b=j/(4*k),b=a?u.ceil(b):u.max((b|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=b*k;j=u.min(4*a,j);if(a){for(var q=0;q<a;q+=k)this._doProcessBlock(e,q);q=e.splice(0,a);c.sigBytes-=j}return new r.init(q,j)},clone:function(){var a=t.clone.call(this);
a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});l.Hasher=q.extend({cfg:t.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){q.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(b,e){return(new a.init(e)).finalize(b)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(b,e){return(new n.HMAC.init(a,
e)).finalize(b)}}});var n=d.algo={};return d}(Math);
(function(){var u=CryptoJS,p=u.lib.WordArray;u.enc.Base64={stringify:function(d){var l=d.words,p=d.sigBytes,t=this._map;d.clamp();d=[];for(var r=0;r<p;r+=3)for(var w=(l[r>>>2]>>>24-8*(r%4)&255)<<16|(l[r+1>>>2]>>>24-8*((r+1)%4)&255)<<8|l[r+2>>>2]>>>24-8*((r+2)%4)&255,v=0;4>v&&r+0.75*v<p;v++)d.push(t.charAt(w>>>6*(3-v)&63));if(l=t.charAt(64))for(;d.length%4;)d.push(l);return d.join("")},parse:function(d){var l=d.length,s=this._map,t=s.charAt(64);t&&(t=d.indexOf(t),-1!=t&&(l=t));for(var t=[],r=0,w=0;w<
l;w++)if(w%4){var v=s.indexOf(d.charAt(w-1))<<2*(w%4),b=s.indexOf(d.charAt(w))>>>6-2*(w%4);t[r>>>2]|=(v|b)<<24-8*(r%4);r++}return p.create(t,r)},_map:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="}})();
(function(u){function p(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(n&a|~n&c)+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}function d(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(n&c|a&~c)+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}function l(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(n^a^c)+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}function s(b,n,a,c,e,j,k){b=b+(a^(n|~c))+e+k;return(b<<j|b>>>32-j)+n}for(var t=CryptoJS,r=t.lib,w=r.WordArray,v=r.Hasher,r=t.algo,b=[],x=0;64>x;x++)b[x]=4294967296*u.abs(u.sin(x+1))|0;r=r.MD5=v.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new w.init([1732584193,4023233417,2562383102,271733878])},
_doProcessBlock:function(q,n){for(var a=0;16>a;a++){var c=n+a,e=q[c];q[c]=(e<<8|e>>>24)&16711935|(e<<24|e>>>8)&4278255360}var a=this._hash.words,c=q[n+0],e=q[n+1],j=q[n+2],k=q[n+3],z=q[n+4],r=q[n+5],t=q[n+6],w=q[n+7],v=q[n+8],A=q[n+9],B=q[n+10],C=q[n+11],u=q[n+12],D=q[n+13],E=q[n+14],x=q[n+15],f=a[0],m=a[1],g=a[2],h=a[3],f=p(f,m,g,h,c,7,b[0]),h=p(h,f,m,g,e,12,b[1]),g=p(g,h,f,m,j,17,b[2]),m=p(m,g,h,f,k,22,b[3]),f=p(f,m,g,h,z,7,b[4]),h=p(h,f,m,g,r,12,b[5]),g=p(g,h,f,m,t,17,b[6]),m=p(m,g,h,f,w,22,b[7]),
f=p(f,m,g,h,v,7,b[8]),h=p(h,f,m,g,A,12,b[9]),g=p(g,h,f,m,B,17,b[10]),m=p(m,g,h,f,C,22,b[11]),f=p(f,m,g,h,u,7,b[12]),h=p(h,f,m,g,D,12,b[13]),g=p(g,h,f,m,E,17,b[14]),m=p(m,g,h,f,x,22,b[15]),f=d(f,m,g,h,e,5,b[16]),h=d(h,f,m,g,t,9,b[17]),g=d(g,h,f,m,C,14,b[18]),m=d(m,g,h,f,c,20,b[19]),f=d(f,m,g,h,r,5,b[20]),h=d(h,f,m,g,B,9,b[21]),g=d(g,h,f,m,x,14,b[22]),m=d(m,g,h,f,z,20,b[23]),f=d(f,m,g,h,A,5,b[24]),h=d(h,f,m,g,E,9,b[25]),g=d(g,h,f,m,k,14,b[26]),m=d(m,g,h,f,v,20,b[27]),f=d(f,m,g,h,D,5,b[28]),h=d(h,f,
m,g,j,9,b[29]),g=d(g,h,f,m,w,14,b[30]),m=d(m,g,h,f,u,20,b[31]),f=l(f,m,g,h,r,4,b[32]),h=l(h,f,m,g,v,11,b[33]),g=l(g,h,f,m,C,16,b[34]),m=l(m,g,h,f,E,23,b[35]),f=l(f,m,g,h,e,4,b[36]),h=l(h,f,m,g,z,11,b[37]),g=l(g,h,f,m,w,16,b[38]),m=l(m,g,h,f,B,23,b[39]),f=l(f,m,g,h,D,4,b[40]),h=l(h,f,m,g,c,11,b[41]),g=l(g,h,f,m,k,16,b[42]),m=l(m,g,h,f,t,23,b[43]),f=l(f,m,g,h,A,4,b[44]),h=l(h,f,m,g,u,11,b[45]),g=l(g,h,f,m,x,16,b[46]),m=l(m,g,h,f,j,23,b[47]),f=s(f,m,g,h,c,6,b[48]),h=s(h,f,m,g,w,10,b[49]),g=s(g,h,f,m,
E,15,b[50]),m=s(m,g,h,f,r,21,b[51]),f=s(f,m,g,h,u,6,b[52]),h=s(h,f,m,g,k,10,b[53]),g=s(g,h,f,m,B,15,b[54]),m=s(m,g,h,f,e,21,b[55]),f=s(f,m,g,h,v,6,b[56]),h=s(h,f,m,g,x,10,b[57]),g=s(g,h,f,m,t,15,b[58]),m=s(m,g,h,f,D,21,b[59]),f=s(f,m,g,h,z,6,b[60]),h=s(h,f,m,g,C,10,b[61]),g=s(g,h,f,m,j,15,b[62]),m=s(m,g,h,f,A,21,b[63]);a[0]=a[0]+f|0;a[1]=a[1]+m|0;a[2]=a[2]+g|0;a[3]=a[3]+h|0},_doFinalize:function(){var b=this._data,n=b.words,a=8*this._nDataBytes,c=8*b.sigBytes;n[c>>>5]|=128<<24-c%32;var e=u.floor(a/
4294967296);n[(c+64>>>9<<4)+15]=(e<<8|e>>>24)&16711935|(e<<24|e>>>8)&4278255360;n[(c+64>>>9<<4)+14]=(a<<8|a>>>24)&16711935|(a<<24|a>>>8)&4278255360;b.sigBytes=4*(n.length+1);this._process();b=this._hash;n=b.words;for(a=0;4>a;a++)c=n[a],n[a]=(c<<8|c>>>24)&16711935|(c<<24|c>>>8)&4278255360;return b},clone:function(){var b=v.clone.call(this);b._hash=this._hash.clone();return b}});t.MD5=v._createHelper(r);t.HmacMD5=v._createHmacHelper(r)})(Math);
(function(){var u=CryptoJS,p=u.lib,d=p.Base,l=p.WordArray,p=u.algo,s=p.EvpKDF=d.extend({cfg:d.extend({keySize:4,hasher:p.MD5,iterations:1}),init:function(d){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(d)},compute:function(d,r){for(var p=this.cfg,s=p.hasher.create(),b=l.create(),u=b.words,q=p.keySize,p=p.iterations;u.length<q;){n&&s.update(n);var n=s.update(d).finalize(r);s.reset();for(var a=1;a<p;a++)n=s.finalize(n),s.reset();b.concat(n)}b.sigBytes=4*q;return b}});u.EvpKDF=function(d,l,p){return s.create(p).compute(d,
l)}})();
CryptoJS.lib.Cipher||function(u){var p=CryptoJS,d=p.lib,l=d.Base,s=d.WordArray,t=d.BufferedBlockAlgorithm,r=p.enc.Base64,w=p.algo.EvpKDF,v=d.Cipher=t.extend({cfg:l.extend(),createEncryptor:function(e,a){return this.create(this._ENC_XFORM_MODE,e,a)},createDecryptor:function(e,a){return this.create(this._DEC_XFORM_MODE,e,a)},init:function(e,a,b){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(b);this._xformMode=e;this._key=a;this.reset()},reset:function(){t.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},process:function(e){this._append(e);return this._process()},
finalize:function(e){e&&this._append(e);return this._doFinalize()},keySize:4,ivSize:4,_ENC_XFORM_MODE:1,_DEC_XFORM_MODE:2,_createHelper:function(e){return{encrypt:function(b,k,d){return("string"==typeof k?c:a).encrypt(e,b,k,d)},decrypt:function(b,k,d){return("string"==typeof k?c:a).decrypt(e,b,k,d)}}}});d.StreamCipher=v.extend({_doFinalize:function(){return this._process(!0)},blockSize:1});var b=p.mode={},x=function(e,a,b){var c=this._iv;c?this._iv=u:c=this._prevBlock;for(var d=0;d<b;d++)e[a+d]^=
c[d]},q=(d.BlockCipherMode=l.extend({createEncryptor:function(e,a){return this.Encryptor.create(e,a)},createDecryptor:function(e,a){return this.Decryptor.create(e,a)},init:function(e,a){this._cipher=e;this._iv=a}})).extend();q.Encryptor=q.extend({processBlock:function(e,a){var b=this._cipher,c=b.blockSize;x.call(this,e,a,c);b.encryptBlock(e,a);this._prevBlock=e.slice(a,a+c)}});q.Decryptor=q.extend({processBlock:function(e,a){var b=this._cipher,c=b.blockSize,d=e.slice(a,a+c);b.decryptBlock(e,a);x.call(this,
e,a,c);this._prevBlock=d}});b=b.CBC=q;q=(p.pad={}).Pkcs7={pad:function(a,b){for(var c=4*b,c=c-a.sigBytes%c,d=c<<24|c<<16|c<<8|c,l=[],n=0;n<c;n+=4)l.push(d);c=s.create(l,c);a.concat(c)},unpad:function(a){a.sigBytes-=a.words[a.sigBytes-1>>>2]&255}};d.BlockCipher=v.extend({cfg:v.cfg.extend({mode:b,padding:q}),reset:function(){v.reset.call(this);var a=this.cfg,b=a.iv,a=a.mode;if(this._xformMode==this._ENC_XFORM_MODE)var c=a.createEncryptor;else c=a.createDecryptor,this._minBufferSize=1;this._mode=c.call(a,
this,b&&b.words)},_doProcessBlock:function(a,b){this._mode.processBlock(a,b)},_doFinalize:function(){var a=this.cfg.padding;if(this._xformMode==this._ENC_XFORM_MODE){a.pad(this._data,this.blockSize);var b=this._process(!0)}else b=this._process(!0),a.unpad(b);return b},blockSize:4});var n=d.CipherParams=l.extend({init:function(a){this.mixIn(a)},toString:function(a){return(a||this.formatter).stringify(this)}}),b=(p.format={}).OpenSSL={stringify:function(a){var b=a.ciphertext;a=a.salt;return(a?s.create([1398893684,
1701076831]).concat(a).concat(b):b).toString(r)},parse:function(a){a=r.parse(a);var b=a.words;if(1398893684==b[0]&&1701076831==b[1]){var c=s.create(b.slice(2,4));b.splice(0,4);a.sigBytes-=16}return n.create({ciphertext:a,salt:c})}},a=d.SerializableCipher=l.extend({cfg:l.extend({format:b}),encrypt:function(a,b,c,d){d=this.cfg.extend(d);var l=a.createEncryptor(c,d);b=l.finalize(b);l=l.cfg;return n.create({ciphertext:b,key:c,iv:l.iv,algorithm:a,mode:l.mode,padding:l.padding,blockSize:a.blockSize,formatter:d.format})},
decrypt:function(a,b,c,d){d=this.cfg.extend(d);b=this._parse(b,d.format);return a.createDecryptor(c,d).finalize(b.ciphertext)},_parse:function(a,b){return"string"==typeof a?b.parse(a,this):a}}),p=(p.kdf={}).OpenSSL={execute:function(a,b,c,d){d||(d=s.random(8));a=w.create({keySize:b+c}).compute(a,d);c=s.create(a.words.slice(b),4*c);a.sigBytes=4*b;return n.create({key:a,iv:c,salt:d})}},c=d.PasswordBasedCipher=a.extend({cfg:a.cfg.extend({kdf:p}),encrypt:function(b,c,d,l){l=this.cfg.extend(l);d=l.kdf.execute(d,
b.keySize,b.ivSize);l.iv=d.iv;b=a.encrypt.call(this,b,c,d.key,l);b.mixIn(d);return b},decrypt:function(b,c,d,l){l=this.cfg.extend(l);c=this._parse(c,l.format);d=l.kdf.execute(d,b.keySize,b.ivSize,c.salt);l.iv=d.iv;return a.decrypt.call(this,b,c,d.key,l)}})}();
(function(){for(var u=CryptoJS,p=u.lib.BlockCipher,d=u.algo,l=[],s=[],t=[],r=[],w=[],v=[],b=[],x=[],q=[],n=[],a=[],c=0;256>c;c++)a[c]=128>c?c<<1:c<<1^283;for(var e=0,j=0,c=0;256>c;c++){var k=j^j<<1^j<<2^j<<3^j<<4,k=k>>>8^k&255^99;l[e]=k;s[k]=e;var z=a[e],F=a[z],G=a[F],y=257*a[k]^16843008*k;t[e]=y<<24|y>>>8;r[e]=y<<16|y>>>16;w[e]=y<<8|y>>>24;v[e]=y;y=16843009*G^65537*F^257*z^16843008*e;b[k]=y<<24|y>>>8;x[k]=y<<16|y>>>16;q[k]=y<<8|y>>>24;n[k]=y;e?(e=z^a[a[a[G^z]]],j^=a[a[j]]):e=j=1}var H=[0,1,2,4,8,
16,32,64,128,27,54],d=d.AES=p.extend({_doReset:function(){for(var a=this._key,c=a.words,d=a.sigBytes/4,a=4*((this._nRounds=d+6)+1),e=this._keySchedule=[],j=0;j<a;j++)if(j<d)e[j]=c[j];else{var k=e[j-1];j%d?6<d&&4==j%d&&(k=l[k>>>24]<<24|l[k>>>16&255]<<16|l[k>>>8&255]<<8|l[k&255]):(k=k<<8|k>>>24,k=l[k>>>24]<<24|l[k>>>16&255]<<16|l[k>>>8&255]<<8|l[k&255],k^=H[j/d|0]<<24);e[j]=e[j-d]^k}c=this._invKeySchedule=[];for(d=0;d<a;d++)j=a-d,k=d%4?e[j]:e[j-4],c[d]=4>d||4>=j?k:b[l[k>>>24]]^x[l[k>>>16&255]]^q[l[k>>>
8&255]]^n[l[k&255]]},encryptBlock:function(a,b){this._doCryptBlock(a,b,this._keySchedule,t,r,w,v,l)},decryptBlock:function(a,c){var d=a[c+1];a[c+1]=a[c+3];a[c+3]=d;this._doCryptBlock(a,c,this._invKeySchedule,b,x,q,n,s);d=a[c+1];a[c+1]=a[c+3];a[c+3]=d},_doCryptBlock:function(a,b,c,d,e,j,l,f){for(var m=this._nRounds,g=a[b]^c[0],h=a[b+1]^c[1],k=a[b+2]^c[2],n=a[b+3]^c[3],p=4,r=1;r<m;r++)var q=d[g>>>24]^e[h>>>16&255]^j[k>>>8&255]^l[n&255]^c[p++],s=d[h>>>24]^e[k>>>16&255]^j[n>>>8&255]^l[g&255]^c[p++],t=
d[k>>>24]^e[n>>>16&255]^j[g>>>8&255]^l[h&255]^c[p++],n=d[n>>>24]^e[g>>>16&255]^j[h>>>8&255]^l[k&255]^c[p++],g=q,h=s,k=t;q=(f[g>>>24]<<24|f[h>>>16&255]<<16|f[k>>>8&255]<<8|f[n&255])^c[p++];s=(f[h>>>24]<<24|f[k>>>16&255]<<16|f[n>>>8&255]<<8|f[g&255])^c[p++];t=(f[k>>>24]<<24|f[n>>>16&255]<<16|f[g>>>8&255]<<8|f[h&255])^c[p++];n=(f[n>>>24]<<24|f[g>>>16&255]<<16|f[h>>>8&255]<<8|f[k&255])^c[p++];a[b]=q;a[b+1]=s;a[b+2]=t;a[b+3]=n},keySize:8});u.AES=p._createHelper(d)})();



                       function encryption(PlainText,key){  
                                   var encrypt = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(PlainText,key);
                                   return(encrypt);  
                                } 
       function decryption(EncrpytData,key){  
          var decrypted =CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(EncrpytData,key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

         return(decrypted);
              }
```

After adding the .js file, add the [Rhino library](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino) to your project for interpreting the javascript code in android. Once, you have added rhino, add the following code in a util class for all encryption and decryption. Call the encryption() and decryption() methods for your purpose.

AesUtil:

```
public class AESUtil{
Context context;
InputStream inputStream;
org.mozilla.javascript.Context rhino;
Scriptable scope;
public AESUtil(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public void set_values()
{
     inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
            context.getResources().getIdentifier("aes",
                    "raw", context.getPackageName()));
    String data = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
    Log.d("animesh_data", data);
    rhino = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();

   // Turn off optimization to make Rhino Android compatible

    rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
    scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
    rhino.evaluateString(scope, data, "JavaScript", 0, null);
}

static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}

public String encrypt( String data, String key)
{
    set_values();
    Object obj = scope.get("encryption", scope);
    if (obj instanceof Function) {
        Function jsFunction = (Function) obj;
        Object[] params = new Object[]{data, key};

        // Call the function with params
        Object jsResult = jsFunction.call(rhino, scope, scope, params);
        // Parse the jsResult object to a String
        String result = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.toString(jsResult);
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt( String data, String key)
{
    set_values();
    Object obj = scope.get("decryption", scope);
    if (obj instanceof Function) {
        Function jsFunction = (Function) obj;
        Object[] params = new Object[]{data, key};
        // Call the function with params
        Object jsResult = jsFunction.call(rhino, scope, scope, params);
        // Parse the jsResult object to a String
        String result = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.toString(jsResult);
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: it will take more time arround ~1 sec for each encryption/decryption

Comment: @RanjithKumar: Its working fine for me. If you get any better and optimal solution than this, then please let me know.

Comment: yes working fine me too. but it will take 1000 ms for each time. Normal encryption takes 5 ms. I will check & update you better solution soon.

Comment: I found better solution, check my answer. But I offered you bounty for another safe solution. thanks for sharing.

Comment: @RanjithKumar: Thank you. I will Implement it  and check once.

Answer (score 3):

Finally i have found a solution from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thackerronak/554c985c3001b16810af5fc0eb5c358f)
This is the case when **the default config is used**

I have ported the code to Kotlin for android

```kotlin
import android.util.Base64
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.util.*
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import kotlin.math.min

/**
 * Conforming with CryptoJS AES method
 */
// see https://gist.github.com/thackerronak/554c985c3001b16810af5fc0eb5c358f
@Suppress("unused", "FunctionName")
object CryptoAES {

    private const val KEY_SIZE = 256
    private const val IV_SIZE = 128
    private const val HASH_CIPHER = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"
    private const val AES = "AES"
    private const val KDF_DIGEST = "MD5"

    // Seriously crypto-js, what's wrong with you?
    private const val APPEND = "Salted__"

    /**
     * Encrypt
     * @param password passphrase
     * @param plainText plain string
     */
    fun encrypt(password: String, plainText: String): String {
        val saltBytes = generateSalt(8)
        val key = ByteArray(KEY_SIZE / 8)
        val iv = ByteArray(IV_SIZE / 8)
        EvpKDF(password.toByteArray(), KEY_SIZE, IV_SIZE, saltBytes, key, iv)
        val keyS = SecretKeySpec(key, AES)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(HASH_CIPHER)
        val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyS, ivSpec)
        val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.toByteArray())
        // Thanks kientux for this: https://gist.github.com/kientux/bb48259c6f2133e628ad
        // Create CryptoJS-like encrypted!
        val sBytes = APPEND.toByteArray()
        val b = ByteArray(sBytes.size + saltBytes.size + cipherText.size)
        System.arraycopy(sBytes, 0, b, 0, sBytes.size)
        System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, b, sBytes.size, saltBytes.size)
        System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, b, sBytes.size + saltBytes.size, cipherText.size)
        val bEncode = Base64.encode(b, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        return String(bEncode)
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt
     * Thanks Artjom B. for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29152379/4405051
     * @param password passphrase
     * @param cipherText encrypted string
     */
    fun decrypt(password: String, cipherText: String): String {
        val ctBytes = Base64.decode(cipherText.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
        val saltBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(ctBytes, 8, 16)
        val cipherTextBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(ctBytes, 16, ctBytes.size)
        val key = ByteArray(KEY_SIZE / 8)
        val iv = ByteArray(IV_SIZE / 8)
        EvpKDF(password.toByteArray(), KEY_SIZE, IV_SIZE, saltBytes, key, iv)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(HASH_CIPHER)
        val keyS = SecretKeySpec(key, AES)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyS, IvParameterSpec(iv))
        val plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherTextBytes)
        return String(plainText)
    }

    private fun EvpKDF(
        password: ByteArray,
        keySize: Int,
        ivSize: Int,
        salt: ByteArray,
        resultKey: ByteArray,
        resultIv: ByteArray
    ): ByteArray {
        return EvpKDF(password, keySize, ivSize, salt, 1, KDF_DIGEST, resultKey, resultIv)
    }

    private fun EvpKDF(
        password: ByteArray,
        keySize: Int,
        ivSize: Int,
        salt: ByteArray,
        iterations: Int,
        hashAlgorithm: String,
        resultKey: ByteArray,
        resultIv: ByteArray
    ): ByteArray {
        val keySize = keySize / 32
        val ivSize = ivSize / 32
        val targetKeySize = keySize + ivSize
        val derivedBytes = ByteArray(targetKeySize * 4)
        var numberOfDerivedWords = 0
        var block: ByteArray? = null
        val hash = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm)
        while (numberOfDerivedWords < targetKeySize) {
            if (block != null) {
                hash.update(block)
            }
            hash.update(password)
            block = hash.digest(salt)
            hash.reset()
            // Iterations
            for (i in 1 until iterations) {
                block = hash.digest(block!!)
                hash.reset()
            }
            System.arraycopy(
                block!!, 0, derivedBytes, numberOfDerivedWords * 4,
                min(block.size, (targetKeySize - numberOfDerivedWords) * 4)
            )
            numberOfDerivedWords += block.size / 4
        }
        System.arraycopy(derivedBytes, 0, resultKey, 0, keySize * 4)
        System.arraycopy(derivedBytes, keySize * 4, resultIv, 0, ivSize * 4)
        return derivedBytes // key + iv
    }

    private fun generateSalt(length: Int): ByteArray {
        return ByteArray(length).apply {
            SecureRandom().nextBytes(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This library working fine for all platforms.

https://github.com/skavinvarnan/Cross-Platform-AES

***For android encryption***

**Step 1 : Use this util class ->** [link](https://github.com/skavinvarnan/Cross-Platform-AES/blob/master/Android/CryptLib.java)

**Step 2: Encrypt & decrypt using this code**

```
try {
String plainText = "this is my plain text";
String key = "simplekey";
String iv = "1234123412341234";

CryptLib cryptLib = new CryptLib();

String encryptedString = cryptLib.encryptSimple(plainText, key, iv);
System.out.println("encryptedString " + encryptedString);

String decryptedString = cryptLib.decryptSimple(encryptedString, key, iv);
System.out.println("decryptedString " + decryptedString);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***Java Script code***

```
var plainText = "this is my plain text";
var key = "simplekey";
var iv = "1234123412341234";

var cryptoLib = require('cryptlib');

shaKey = cryptoLib.getHashSha256(key, 32); // This line is not needed on Android or iOS. Its already built into CryptLib.m and CryptLib.java

var encryptedString = cryptoLib.encrypt(plainText, shaKey, iv);
console.log('encryptedString %s', encryptedString);

var decryptedString = cryptoLib.decrypt(encryptedString, shaKey, iv);
console.log('decryptedString %s', decryptedString);
```

***For iOS users use this sample***

https://github.com/skavinvarnan/Cross-Platform-AES/tree/master/iOS

All platforms produce same following output

> **encryptedString:** rKzNsa7Qzk9TExJ6aHg49tGDiritTUJ08RMPm48S0o4=
>
> **decryptedString:** this is my plain text