# How to decrypt password from JavaScript CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, passphrase) in Python

Tags: javascript, python, aes, pycrypto, cryptojs

I have a password which is encrypt from JavaScript via

```js
  var password = 'sample'
  var passphrase ='sample_passphrase'
  CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, passphrase)
```

Then I tried to decrypt the password comes from JavaScript in Python:

```py
  from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  import base64

  PADDING = '\0'

  pad_it = lambda s: s+(16 - len(s)%16)*PADDING
  key = 'sample_passphrase'
  iv='11.0.0.101'        #------> here is my question, how can I get this iv to restore password, what should I put here?
  key=pad_it(key)        #------> should I add padding to keys and iv?
  iv=pad_it(iv)          ##
  source = 'sample'
  generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB,iv)
  crypt = generator.encrypt(pad_it(source))
  cryptedStr = base64.b64encode(crypt)
  print cryptedStr
  generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
  recovery = generator.decrypt(crypt)
  print recovery.rstrip(PADDING)
```

I checked JS from browser console, it shows IV in `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, passphrase)` is a object with some attributes( like `sigBytes:16, words: [-44073646, -1300128421, 1939444916, 881316061]`). It seems generated randomly.

From one web page, it tells me that JS has two way to encrypt password 
([reference link](http://www.cnblogs.com/Lifehacker/p/nodejs_aes_encrypt_problem.html) ):

> - a. `crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password)`
> - b. `crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)`

What I saw in JavaScript should be option a. However, only option b is equivalent to AES.new() in python.

**The questions are**:

1. How can I restore this password in Python without changing JavaScript code?
2. If I need IV in Python, how can I get it from the password that is used in JavaScript?

Comment: CryptoJS AES defaults to CBC mode, so no CBF mode in python needed. AES.encrypt returns also a object. with toString() you get a base64 encoded blob containing salt, iv and message. All of them you need to seperate end feed into Python. also, be aware that password and key are 2 different things.

Comment: Thanks,  just modify key to sample_passphrase, so it will be more clear. but it what if I cannot get toString() output? Is this become a impossible job? @SKR

Comment: so you mean you have no control at all over the js? How does the js-code continue? what happens with the object returned by encrypt? You need to get the salt and iv out of the js somehow. Or do you just want to "mock" the behavior of the js and generate  a similar encrypted message for a external api or something?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have no control at all over the js. I can only get the password string as a single input.  What I want to is create a same password as javascript generated so I can use it to pass some web testing from python.  @SKR

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You will have to implement OpenSSL's [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html), because that is what CryptoJS uses to derive the key and IV from the provided password, but pyCrypto only supports the key+IV type encryption. CryptoJS also generates a random salt which also must be send to the server. If the ciphertext object is converted to a string, then it uses automatically an OpenSSL-compatible format which includes the random salt.

```js
var data = "Some semi-long text for testing";
var password = "some password";
var ctObj = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, password);
var ctStr = ctObj.toString();

out.innerHTML = ctStr;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Possible output:

> U2FsdGVkX1+ATH716DgsfPGjzmvhr+7+pzYfUzR+25u0D7Z5Lw04IJ+LmvPXJMpz

CryptoJS defaults to 256 bit key size for AES, PKCS#7 padding and CBC mode. AES has a 128 bit block size which is also the IV size. This means that we have to request 32+16 = 48 byte from EVP_BytesToKey. I've found a semi-functional implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/gsakkis/4546068) and extended it further.

Here is the full Python (tested with 2.7 and 3.4) code, which is compatible with CryptoJS:

```
from Cryptodome import Random
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
import base64
from hashlib import md5

BLOCK_SIZE = 16

def pad(data):
    length = BLOCK_SIZE - (len(data) % BLOCK_SIZE)
    return data + (chr(length)*length).encode()

def unpad(data):
    return data[:-(data[-1] if type(data[-1]) == int else ord(data[-1]))]

def bytes_to_key(data, salt, output=48):
    # extended from https://gist.github.com/gsakkis/4546068
    assert len(salt) == 8, len(salt)
    data += salt
    key = md5(data).digest()
    final_key = key
    while len(final_key) < output:
        key = md5(key + data).digest()
        final_key += key
    return final_key[:output]

def encrypt(message, passphrase):
    salt = Random.new().read(8)
    key_iv = bytes_to_key(passphrase, salt, 32+16)
    key = key_iv[:32]
    iv = key_iv[32:]
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(b"Salted__" + salt + aes.encrypt(pad(message)))

def decrypt(encrypted, passphrase):
    encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted)
    assert encrypted[0:8] == b"Salted__"
    salt = encrypted[8:16]
    key_iv = bytes_to_key(passphrase, salt, 32+16)
    key = key_iv[:32]
    iv = key_iv[32:]
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(aes.decrypt(encrypted[16:]))


password = "some password".encode()
ct_b64 = "U2FsdGVkX1+ATH716DgsfPGjzmvhr+7+pzYfUzR+25u0D7Z5Lw04IJ+LmvPXJMpz"

pt = decrypt(ct_b64, password)
print("pt", pt)

print("pt", decrypt(encrypt(pt, password), password))
```

---

Similar code can be found in my answers for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27250883/1816580) and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678978/1816580).

JavaScript AES encryption in the browser without HTTPS is simple obfuscation and does not provide any real security, because the key must be transmitted alongside the ciphertext.

**[UPDATE]:**

You [should use pycryptodome instead of pycrypto](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/issues/285) because pycrypto([latest pypi version is 2.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/)) no longer maintained and it has vulnerabilities [CVE-2013-7459](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cq27-v7xp-c356) and [CVE-2018-6594](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-6528-wvf6-f6qg) (CVE warning reported by github). I choose `pycryptodomex` package here(`Cryptodome` replace `Crypto` in code) instead of `pycryptodome` package [to avoid conflict name](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/introduction.html) with `Crypto` from `pycrypto` package.

Comment: Have tried this one, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot. I don't know much on how encrypt and decrypt work with these options, if you could mark some reference links I can get these info, that will be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which references you're looking for. If you're talking about how I know all this, then the easiest way would be to simply take the unminified source code and read it.

Comment: Yes, I mean how to get these info. I will check some code. thanks.

Comment: Awesome code. Thank you. Spend a lot of time in cryptojs code trying to figure this out

Comment: great work, it is exactly what i have been searching for in past few hours, thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you Artjom, It really works for most of the cases, however sometimes, I get an AssertionError for `assert encrypted[0:8] == b"Salted__"` line that runs on decrypt function. Currently, I'm looking for the reason of that by repating the erroneous case.

Comment: @EmreCanKucukoglu Are you sending the value through HTTP? If so, are you encoding it correctly? This might be an issue, because Base64 is not URL-safe in its default form. If this is not it, you need to ask a proper question with some examples.

Comment: Yes, I am sending the values through HTTP. I use it like that:
`body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`
`encrypted_data = body['encrypted_data']`
`pw = body['pw'].encode()`
`result = crypto.decrypt(encrypted_data, pw).decode()`

Then, I understand that I have to encode also encrypted_data, right?

Comment: It occurs actually because of some other problems, I suppose. I dig into logs and realize that request body has some erroneous parts for my case. Sorry for that and thanks again Artjom.

Comment: @Fruit Thank you for the edit. Do you know what the incompatibilities between pycrypto and pycryptodome are when switching to pycryptodome?

Comment: @ArtjomB. It has been documented at https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/vs_pycrypto.html

Comment: You life saviour

Comment: After a lot of tries with other solutions, this works perfectly fine. Thank so much!

Comment: Don't forget to decode your string.`return unpad(aes.decrypt(encrypted[16:])).decode()`

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am using this script in my app to encrypt some content. (https://embed.plnkr.co/0VPU1zmmWC5wmTKPKnhg/).
Password => PBKDF2 key derivation => AES encryption
I tried to encrypt/decrypt the content through python script you suggested above but it fails. Can you help here please?