# How to emulate Javascript crypto AES-256-CBC decipher in Java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes

I have the following Javascript code in a web page:

```
  var decrypt = function (text, password){
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',password);
    var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
  }
```

, and I'm trying to reproduce it using Java, using the following:

```
static MessageDigest MD5 = null;

static {
    try {
        MD5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String password)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] passwordBytes = hexStringToByteArray(password);
    byte[] keyBytes = MD5.digest(passwordBytes);
    byte[] keyAndPassword = new byte[keyBytes.length + passwordBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, keyAndPassword, 0, keyBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(passwordBytes, 0, keyAndPassword, keyBytes.length, passwordBytes.length);
    byte[] ivBytes = MD5.digest(keyAndPassword);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    byte[] encrypted = hexStringToByteArray(cipherText);
    Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    aesCBC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    byte[] decryptedData = aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted);
    return new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

which pieces bits from:

- [Encrypt with Node.js Crypto module and decrypt with Java (in Android app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787773/encrypt-with-node-js-crypto-module-and-decrypt-with-java-in-android-app)
- [CryptoJS AES encryption and Java AES decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432896/cryptojs-aes-encryption-and-java-aes-decryption)

, but I get "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded", on parameters which the JS function decodes correctly.

Note that [Given final block not properly padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872) does not answer this question- as it is obvious that this is a padding problem but the solution is to replicate whatever the JS crypto lib does, which is not well documented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given final block not properly padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded)

Comment: @MattClark I have taken a look at that answer, but to solve this specific issue one needs to take into consideration how does the Javascript decipher function work, which that answer doesn't.

Comment: You will need to provide example inputs and outputs. I'm particularly curious about the password string.

Comment: Possible useful other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762098/how-to-decrypt-password-from-javascript-cryptojs-aes-encryptpassword-passphras/36780727#36780727

Comment: See the great Artjom B's answer linked from my previous comment.  Look at what he does with the salt to derive the IV.  You need to do the same.  It looks like the salt should be part of the ciphertext.

Comment: @MattClark I don't think that link is relevant.  The problem here is peculiarities of how Crypto-JS does its password based encryption.  For Alex's code to be compatible with Crypto-JS, he needs to derive the key and IV in a similar fashion that Crypto-JS does.

Comment: In any case, after further investigation, using the JS version would be quite enough for my purposes, so I no longer care much about this. If SO has a policy of removing unanswered, not worthwhile questions, this would be a good candidate.